# How to pass URL parameters to a Lightning App page, to load LWC in context of a record?

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components, url, flexipages

I want to make a standalone salesforce page that loads data specific to a current member. I tried making an App page, however when I load `/lightning/n/MyAppPage?recordId=something` it redirects to `/lightning/n/MyAppPage and drops` the URL param.

Essentially what I want to do is make a standalone LWC in a standalone tab that loads data specific to an Account. I want to link out to this page from the Account view page and pass the account to my standalone LWC page as some sort of context. How can I link to such a page? I can't use the record type (Account's) view Flexipage as that has its own layout I can't overwrite for the current logged in user.

Comment: did you manage to make it work?

Comment: @glls yes, custom params appear to be the right way. The hash is not meant for this use case so I'm happy there's a semi-standard one. localStorage shouldn't be used for this kind of use case.

Comment: glad you were able to resolve.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is native support for query parameters in LWC. To persist, their names need to have namespace added as a prefix. Default namespace is `c__`.

In this example:
`/lightning/n/MyAppPage?recordId=something`, `recordId` will be auto-stripped.

However, in this example: `/lightning/n/MyAppPage?c__recordId=something`, `c__recordId` will persist.

To read query params you can leverage `CurrentPageReference` wire, which receives object with a `state` attribute, which contains all the query params.
The wire auto-executes, when detects any change in URL.

```js
import { LightningElement, track, wire } from 'lwc';
import { CurrentPageReference, NavigationMixin } from 'lightning/navigation';

export default class AccountParameters extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement) {

    @track currentPageReference;
    @wire(CurrentPageReference)
    setCurrentPageReference(currentPageReference) {
        this.currentPageReference = currentPageReference;
    }

    get recordId() {
        return this.currentPageReference?.state?.c__recordId;
    }

    get objectType() {
        return this.currentPageReference?.state?.c__objectType;
    }

    get countParam() {
        return this.currentPageReference?.state?.c__randomCountParam;
    }

    // Navigates to app page on button click
    handleNavigate() {
        this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
            type: 'standard__navItemPage',
            attributes: {
                apiName: 'AccountsAppPageName',
            },
            state: {
                c__recordId: '001B000001KGVlCIAX',
                c__objectType: 'Account',
                c__randomCountParam: 3
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Related links:

- https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.use_navigate_add_params_url
- https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.reference_page_reference_type

Comment: Thank you. `@track` is deprecated unless you mutate the reference. Also, is there a way to do this without using Salesforce's horrible wire service?

Comment: It works perfectly. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

For persistence, I would recommend using [location history hash](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_loc_hash.asp) also known as a [fragment identifier](https://www.w3.org/DesignIssues/Fragment.html)
it can easily be added by accessting wht browser's location object:

```
location.hash = 'your hash'
```

. They are not only persistent, but you can also track changes to it using a [hashchange](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onhashchange) event handler if need be

So, instead of

```
/lightning/n/MyAppPage?recordId=something
```

you would end p having something that resembles:

```
/lightning/n/MyAppPage#recordId=something
```

since fragment identifier parameters are not sent to the server, they do not trigger a reload of the page.

If you are looking for storage option that you can use from the browser, you can use sessionStorage or localStorage if the data needs to persist beyond the users session

Comment: Might be a good hack workaround for Salesforce's poor application design, I'm also curious if there's other options as the window hash isn't ideal for storing data

Comment: If you want to store actual data, use browser storage, such as sessionStorage or localstorage

Comment: How would you reference this in an LWC?  Can you provide a code sample for that?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Comment: you can use connectedCallback to read from localstorage (or any other event handler based on your needs)

Comment: Sorry, not asking about Local Storage, as that was an aside.  I was asking about referencing the fragment identifier.  Without that information, this is an incomplete answer.

Comment: The link documentation on the fragment identifier contains  the syntax, however, i've added a 1 liner with an extract from the link. Hope this helps

Comment: Huh. I'd always thought that accessing location wasn't recommended in an LWC, hence currentpagereference and the navigation mixin, though I can't seem to find a reference to avoiding the use of hash.  Interesting.

Comment: I use it for single page/component apps in lwc, haven't run any issues with, it is recommended to use the other answers approach, however, this is a standard web practice, mostly when developing single page applications