# Is anything wrong about navigating to lwc components through url?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components, navigationmixin.navigate

I just stumbled over this [SE answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/404993/2513) about navigating to LWC components by directly calling a URL.

```
this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
    type: 'standard__webPage',
    attributes: {
        url: '/one/one.app#' + btoa(JSON.stringify({"componentDef" : "c:sendQuoteEmail"}))
    }
})
```

It works quite well for me and I wonder if this is documented and safe to use, or if I should avoid doing it...

While doing some research about the componentDef, I stumbled over some references to the deprecated aura navigation using [e.force:navigateToComponent](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_navigation_migrate_to_isUrlAddressable.htm), so I wonder if this hidden feature is some aura legacy that might stay around untouched for some time ;)

Comment: It's undocumented and could break. I wouldn't do it myself (but then I work for an ISV so we cannot use this sort of hack as it may impact a lot of customers if the hack stops working).

Answer (score 0):

The final link in your question contains your answer. Use [lightning:navigation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:navigation/specification) or [lightning-navigation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-navigation/documentation) using the type `standard__component` rather than encoding a payload with `standard__webPage`. This method should be reliable for years to come.

Comment: The downside here is, that it does not support LWC but only aura, and with the URL hack I am able to avoid an additional wrapper component. I am tired of aura wrappers, to be honest...

Comment: @itsmebasti It's probably low priority, given that there are workarounds, though. For example, a single Aura component could have a parameter to initialize a LWC dynamically.